# Question about the value of angular displacement

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, angular-velocity, displacement

Can angular displacement be greater than $2\pi$ radians?

[image]

Is $5760$ radians correct here or should we do something like this:

$\frac{5760}{2\pi} = 916.732472209$

$0.732472209 \cdot 2\pi = 4.60225862151$

I got this asked in an exam an thought we should do like the way I did here. Am I right?

Edit: Just thinking about that the angular displacement cannot be bounded since the derivation of the other things like angular velocity, angular acceleration etc. comes from it and it somehow bounds them, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were asked for the angular displacement of a point on wheel 4, you might want to subtract out the integer number of revolutions. For the wheel itself, I would think that the 5760 radians should be acceptable.